# Static class missing on remote staging server

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Inside the root `<template>` element of `/pages/_id.vue` (Nuxt application) I have a root `<div>` element with a static class ("template") and a dynamic class ("fullHeight").

These two classes work perfectly on my local machine - in the DOM I see:

```html
<div class="app" data-v-8b925e14>
  <div class="template fullHeight" data-v-8b925e14>
```

But they're missing on my remote staging server:

```html
<div class="app" data-v-314f53c6>
  <div data-v-314f53c6>
```

It's the same codebase so I don't know why both classes even the static one are missing. Here's `_id.vue`:

```html
<template>
  <div
    class="template"
    :class="{ fullHeight: !configIsLoaded }"
  >
    <template v-if="configIsLoaded">
      some content
    </template>

    <template v-else>
      <div class="container error">
        404
      </div>
    </template>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex'

export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapState({
      configIsLoaded: state => state.omni?.configIsLoaded ?? ''
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: ideally you should be doing `:class="['template', { fullHeight: !configIsLoaded }]"`

Comment: Weird usage of `mapState` IMO. Still, are you sure that `configIsLoaded` is set as an `env variable` on the server? Btw, `!!` of something that fallbacks to `''` is still `false`. So that should explain why you don't have the `fullHeight` class (which should be `full-height` btw). @LawrenceCherone I don't see any issue with letting it in `class` so far, since it's clear that `class` is static and `:class` is dynamic. Do you have any reference that this is better?

Comment: @kissu fewer lines is enough for me, though also vue would parse the element props nanoseconds faster too, as there are less props to parse, is in src/compiler/helpers.js on github

Comment: @kissu when `configIsLoaded` is false (I know it is because I see `<div class="container error">` in the DOM, then `:class="{ fullHeight: !configIsLoaded }"` should work and I should see a class of `fullHeight` in the DOM. Which I don't.

Comment: What if you debug with a `{{ configIsLoaded }}` in your template to double-check the value at a specific point? Also, maybe double check your `mapState`, not sure that it's needed, should probably be replaced by a simpler `computed` or even a `mapGetter` IMO.

Comment: configIsLoaded: state => state.omni?.configIsLoaded ?? ''

If configIsLoaded is supposed to be a boolean, why are you setting it to an empty string? To me the part  ?? "" seems unnecessary